# axios post a archivo php me duelve el codigo del archivo php

Tags: php, vue.js, axios

Estoy haciendo un post con axios a un archivo php, algo muy simple, este es el codigo:

```
  axios
      .post("/tabla/enviar.php", {
        request: 1,
      })
      .then((request) => {
        console.log(request.data);
      });
```

el codigo del archivo php es este:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);

$request = $data->request;

if($request == 1){
    $file = fopen("tabla2.csv","r");

    while(! feof($file))
      {
      print_r(fgetcsv($file));
      }

    fclose($file);
}
```

El problema surge en la respuesta de la peticion post la cual me devuelve el codigo dentro del archivo php, es decir, me devuelve esto:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);

$request = $data->request;

if($request == 1){
    $file = fopen("tabla2.csv","r");

    while(! feof($file))
      {
      print_r(fgetcsv($file));
      }

    fclose($file);
}
```

Que estoy haciendo mal con la este codigo??, muchas gracias por su ayuda

Comment: Cuando te regresa el código, muy probablemente no se esta ejecutando php correctamente en el ambiente que estas utilizando, revisa si el servicio esta correctamente instalado o si esta iniciado

Comment: Muchas gracias, use wamp server y todo bien